# The cursor inside stored procedure not working as expected

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have an sql stored procedure, but when I execute it it is not returning the desired out put.  Can someone please tell me what I'm doign wrong here...

I put some print statements in there to debug.. the problem seems to be that the cursor is not fetching any results. the result of @@fetch_status is -1

Here is my stored procedure in question:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spComplaintsEmailAlert_autoFillForm] (@counterVal int,
@RESULT varchar(50) OUTPUT,
@RESULTDESC varchar(max) OUTPUT)
AS
  DECLARE @dateEmailSend varchar(50),
          @counter int,
          @region varchar(50),
          @ola_company varchar(50),
          @obj_identified_as varchar(50),
          @product_involved varchar(50),
          @ola_customer varchar(50),
          @product_ut varchar(50);

  DECLARE otherCounterVals CURSOR FOR
  SELECT
    A.CounterVal
  FROM [cmpEmailAlerted] A,
       [cmpTblProductComplaints] B
  WHERE A.CounterVal = B.Counter
  AND CONVERT(varchar(10), A.dateEmailSend, 120) = @dateEmailSend
  AND B.[Company] = @ola_company
  AND B.[Object Identified As] = @obj_identified_as
  AND B.[Product Involved] = @product_involved
  AND B.Region = @region
  AND B.[Customer] = @ola_customer
  AND A.CounterVal != @counter;

  DECLARE @aCounter int;

  BEGIN

    SELECT
      @dateEmailSend = CONVERT(varchar(10), A.dateEmailSend, 120),
      @counter = B.Counter,
      @region = B.Region,
      @ola_company = B.[Company],
      @obj_identified_as = B.[Object Identified As],
      @product_involved = B.[Product Involved],
      @ola_customer = B.[Customer],
      @product_ut = CONVERT(varchar(10), B.[produt u/t], 120)
    FROM [cmpEmailAlerted] A,
         [cmpTblProductComplaints] B
    WHERE A.CounterVal = @counterVal
    AND a.CounterVal = B.Counter;


    OPEN otherCounterVals;
    FETCH NEXT FROM otherCounterVals INTO @aCounter;
    PRINT @@fetch_status;

    PRINT 'start of the loop';
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

    BEGIN
      PRINT 'in the loop';
      SELECT
        @RESULTDESC = concat(@resultdesc, @aCounter, ',');

      FETCH NEXT FROM otherCounterVals INTO @aCounter;

    END;

    PRINT 'out the loop';

    CLOSE otherCounterVals;
    DEALLOCATE otherCounterVals;

    --remove the last comma from the resultdesc
    IF (SUBSTRING(@RESULTDESC, LEN(@RESULTDESC), 1) = ',')
    BEGIN
      SELECT
        @RESULTDESC = SUBSTRING(@RESULTDESC, 0, (LEN(@RESULTDESC)));
    END

    SELECT
      @RESULT = 'SUCCESS';

  END;
```

Here is the output i am getting:

> -1 start of the loop out the loop
>
> (1 row affected)
>
> (1 row affected)

Comment: Why are you using a cursor here in the first place? There are far easier and faster solution for generating a delimited list. You should start using ANSI-92 style joins. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins They have been around for more than 25 years now. Also, use aliases that provide some benefit, not just random characters. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Comment: Thanks. I'll update the query as u suggested.  can you tell me why this is not working here? or show me the other way that you mentioned in the comment?

Comment: maybe your cursor only has one value? What does that query return? Also, why the global, writable, scroll-able cursor?

Comment: Dose the SELECT that defines the cursor return the rows you're expecting? Can you show an example result set that you get from the select? It seems the SELECT that defines the cursor just isn't returning any rows.

Comment: How do you expect the first select to return anything?  None of the @ have a value yet.

Comment: @paparazzo I moved the declaration of the cursor after the select statement... now its working as expected.. I am fairly new to sql... is the cursor result being fetched when i do open_cursor or even before that?

Comment: @SeanLange I moved the cursor after the select and it seems to work.

Comment: I kind of thought all declarations needs to be at the beginning of a stored procedure...

Comment: i'd make that cursor LOCAL FAST_FORWARD if your going to stick with this method since you are doing a single pass. You'll appreciate the performance gain I think.

Comment: A better solution would be to get rid of that cursor entirely. There seems to be no reason to do this RBAR (row by agonizing row). Using STUFF and FOR XML is a better way to generate a delimited list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to just build up a comma delimited string of results, there are much, much easier ways of doing it. A straight-forward, naïve way that doesn't rely on any magic STUFF functionality is simply this pattern:

```
DECLARE @result varchar(max);
SET @result = '';
SELECT @result = @result + ',' + ColumnValueToUse FROM MyTable WHERE <somecondition>
PRINT @result;
```

You can then peel off the first comma. The result will be every value of "ColumValueToUse" in the "MyTable" table that meets whatever the condition is.... all concatenated together and comma separated.  There are fancier ways to do this with STUFF() and FOR XML that handle the comma thing better, and let you do even more fancy stuff.

It's ridiculous to use an expensive cursor (that isn't even declared FAST_FORWARD) for this. Please don't.

As for why your cursor solution isn't working, first ensure your SELECT statement returns the rows you want. Given you don't actually set any of the variables used by the SELECT in the cursor definition, it probably doesn't. But mostly just remove the cursor, please.

Trying to extrapolate from your own example, something like this:

```
DECLARE @result varchar(max);
SET @result = '';
SELECT @result = @result + ',' + A.CounterVal
  FROM [cmpEmailAlerted] A,
       [cmpTblProductComplaints] B
  WHERE A.CounterVal = B.Counter
  AND CONVERT(varchar(10), A.dateEmailSend, 120) = @dateEmailSend
  AND B.[Company] = @ola_company
  AND B.[Object Identified As] = @obj_identified_as
  AND B.[Product Involved] = @product_involved
  AND B.Region = @region
  AND B.[Customer] = @ola_customer
  AND A.CounterVal != @counter;
SELECT @result;
```

Comment: Thanks I will rewrite it using this approach.  But can you help me with my question.. is it ok to declare cursors/variables anywhere inside the stored procedure?

Comment: You can declare them anywhere... but if you're using variables in the definition of the SELECT of a cursor, those should be declared and set PRIOR to defining the cursor.  There are plenty of available references for proper cursor patterns, but in general AVOID USING CURSORS. They should be your last resort, not your first attempt. Learn to use "set-based" operations, as that's what SQL servers excel at.

Comment: I tried that approach. however it only prints out one value. the output I get is ",25682"

Comment: Are you including the entire select? Get your select working with SELECT * to return all the rows. Once that's working, replace the * with the variable = ',' + <whatever you want to compute to add to the string>    Then print out the variable after the select. You should get exactly what you want if you've done it right.

Comment: I added some code I think should be more clear to you.

Comment: ok that worked.. I was doing SELECT .@result =  ',' + A.CounterVal instead of SELECT .@result = .@result + ',' + A.CounterVal

Comment: Thanks a lot and I'll keep the rule in mind that cursors last!! :)

Answer (score 2):

The @ values are not yet defined for the first cursor listed.

Comment: I moved the declaration of the cursor after the select.. that worked as expected. can a cursor be declared anywhere inside a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You need an inner cursor per row of the SELECT statement as well as an outer cursor for the outer SELECT statement.